# Unable to connect to Neo4j database hosted on GrapheneDb.com through code hosted on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: neo4j, pythonanywhere, graphenedb

Ok so i have a free instance of Neo4j on graphenedb, and my code is hosted on a free instance for pythonanywhere. I am a student and doing for experiment so didn't buy paid versions.
Basically whenever i try to access graphenedb neo4j through pythonanywhere i get internal server error 500.
I am using neo4j-driver, and here is a snippet

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

@app.route('/login', methods =['GET','POST'])
def login():
    user = 'xyz'
    passw ='xyzxyz'
    gdb1 =  GraphDatabase.driver(bolt_url, auth=basic_auth(usr_nm_db, pswrd_db))
```

i am getting error on this last line . Unable to connect.
this is the error : neobolt.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection to ('34.229.164.223', 24787) (reason [Errno 111] Connection refused)
Can anyone please help

Comment: Did you use the example from the graphenedb docs page?

Comment: You should probably also not create a new driver per REST call, but one when you start up your app. You might also need to set `encrypted=True` not sure of what the config is in graphenedb

Comment: It won't work on free account on PythonAnywhere. It should be possible on a hacker account. It looks like non-http/https connection, so it's not available on a free account.

Comment: @Filip Yes this solved my query, problem was with PythonAnywhere free account not allowing the connection. I switched to Heroku free account for now and it works! thanks Filip